# listbox count items from another class returns always 0

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, listbox

```
            Frm Form1 = new Frm();
                //here I always get the count =0
            if (Form1 .listBox2 .SelectedItems .Count  > 0)
            {
                string item;
                foreach (int i in Form1.listBox2.SelectedIndices)
                {
                    item = Form1.listBox2.Items[i].ToString();
```

and when I do the same in Frm I get the real number of selected items here's the code in Frm

```
    public  void btnPostText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox2.ClearSelected();
        if (listBox1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (int index in listBox1.SelectedIndices)
                listBox2.SetSelected(index, true);
        }
```

from my program I am trying to post to more than one group at facebook at the same time after the log in process the user selects the groups names that he/she wants to post to at litBox1 in listBox2 there's the groups id(s) in the same order , so when user clicks on the btnPostText I move the selection from listBox1 to listBox2' ,,, Now in Class2` I want to know if any Items are selected in listBox2 ,, the first code is in Class2. PostImg public static bool PostImg( , , ,)

Class2 contains the post procedures just like the Postimg it returns true if posted or false if not

here I am calling it in Frm

```
  if (Class2.PostImage(AppSettings.Default.AccessToken, textbox1.Text, textboxpic.Text) == true)
                MessageBox.Show("Post Done");
```

the code in Class2 is

```
    public static bool PostImage(string AccessToken, string Status, string ImagePath) 
    {
        try
        {
            Frm Frm = new Frm();

            if (Frm .listBox2 .SelectedItems .Count  > 0)
            {
                string item;
                foreach (int i in Frm.listBox2.SelectedIndices)
                {
                    item = Frm.listBox2.Items[i].ToString();
                    groupid = item;


                    FacebookClient fbpost = new FacebookClient(AccessToken);
                    var imgstream = File.OpenRead(ImagePath);
                    dynamic res = fbpost.Post("/" + groupid + "/photos", new
                   {
                       message = Status,
                       File = new FacebookMediaStream
                       {

                           ContentType = "image/jpg",
                           FileName = Path.GetFileName(ImagePath)
                       }.SetValue(imgstream)

                   });

                    result = true;

                }
            }
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: How is listbox2 populated? It seems to me you're making a **new** instance of Frm so listbox2 in that one is still empty.

Comment: so I need to refill it with the same items in the other class???

Comment: Presumably, the user clicks btnPostText after they've selected some items in the box.  In what class is your first example located?  Perhaps you need to grab a reference to an already-open instance of `Frm` rather than creating a new instance.

Comment: @ميداني حر No. You need to get a reference to the actual Frm instance you need. Here you are creating a new one.

Comment: I have 2 classes `Frm` and `Class2` 
the first example is in `Frm`

Comment: just some can tell me how to get a reference to the actual Frm???

Comment: @ميداني حر without knowing how your program is structured, we can't. Where is the wrong code being called? How is that class instantiated? ... etc.

Comment: @ميداني حر Just give a very thorough description of what you're doing. How are you openinig your forms? Where is the problematic call being made? Just edit your answers with as much detail as you can.

Comment: What is Class2? What instantiates it? And please move all these details to the question and out of the comments.

Comment: What instantiates Class2? In other words, where in the program do you use it? Post code if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first, some basics. `Class2` and `Frm` are two distinct classes. *Normally* they cannot see each other unless you pass a reference between them.

`Frm` can see the `PostImage` method inside Class2 because it was marked as `static`. But it doesn't go the other way. So you need to pass a reference to `Frm` when you call `PostImage`. Easiest way of doing this is including it in the method signature:

```
public static bool PostImage(string AccessToken, string Status, string ImagePath, Frm MyForm)
```

Now you call it:

```
if (Class2.PostImage(AppSettings.Default.AccessToken, textbox1.Text, textboxpic.Text, this) == true)
```

Notice how we passed `this` as a parameter in the function. This is the reference we are going to use inside `PostImage`:

```
if (MyForm.listBox2.SelectedItems .Count  > 0)
```

And so on and so forth. The variable `MyForm` is now a reference to the form that called `Class2.PostImage`.

Answer (score 1):

Then you should pass reference to your form (or listBox) as a parameter of the `PostImg` method.

```
public static bool PostImg(Frm form, string AccessToken, string Status, string ImagePath )
{
    try
    {
        if (form.listBox2.SelectedItems.Count  > 0)
        {
            string item;
            foreach (int i in form.listBox2.SelectedIndices)
            {
                item = form.listBox2.Items[i].ToString();
                groupid = item;


                FacebookClient fbpost = new FacebookClient(AccessToken);
                var imgstream = File.OpenRead(ImagePath);
                dynamic res = fbpost.Post("/" + groupid + "/photos", new
               {
                   message = Status,
                   File = new FacebookMediaStream
                   {

                       ContentType = "image/jpg",
                       FileName = Path.GetFileName(ImagePath)
                   }.SetValue(imgstream)

               });

                result = true;

            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

And call it from the method in your form like this:

```
if (Class2.PostImage(this, AppSettings.Default.AccessToken, textbox1.Text, textboxpic.Text) == true)
                MessageBox.Show("Post Done");
```

Comment: Class2.PostImg( `what should I pass here`,accesstoken,text,text);

Comment: The call is at the end of the answer if you are calling from the method of your form.